# tree of d3.js looks so crowd when too many data exist

Tags: d3.js

i want to use d3.js to make data show in a tree. This is what I have done ,there is a problem that the svg will be so crowd when there are many data exist

Can you help me make it look better. 
Here is my code

```
    function update(source) {
    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(), links = tree.links(nodes);
    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
    });
    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });
    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                    })
                    .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
             .attr("r", 1e-6)
             .style("fill", function(d) {
                 return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
             });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em").attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition().duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                    });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
              .attr("r", 4.5)
              .style("fill", function(d) {
                  if (d._children) {
                      return "lightsteelblue";
                  }
                  if (d.isHealth != undefined) {
                      return d.isHealth == false ? "red" : "green";
                  }
              });

    nodeUpdate.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition().duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                    }).remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link").data(links, function(d) {
        return d.target.id;
    });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {
                        x : source.x0,
                        y : source.y0
                    };
                    return diagonal({
                        source : o,
                        target : o
                    });
                });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition().duration(duration).attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition().duration(duration)
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {
                        x : source.x,
                        y : source.y
                    };
                    return diagonal({
                        source : o,
                        target : o
                    });
                }).remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}
```

Comment: get a working fiddle together otherwise we cant test the code properly

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. And I solved it by using [nodeSize](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Tree-Layout.md#nodeSize).

```
tree.nodeSize([x, y])
```

It will set separation between nodes. But this method will override the     `tree.size()`
so you need to recount the coordinate about another nodes.

I hope my answer will help you.